# Search a variable value as ID in html file

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to ask for your help in having a web site that uses the following javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
        var secondLevelLocation = pathArray[0];
        var newPathname = "";
    for (i = 0; i < pathArray.length; i++) {
      newPathname += "";
      newPathname += pathArray[i];
    }   

    var str = "asd fgh roof_material"; 
    var res = str.match(newPathname);

        if (res) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  res;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  "Basic text";
        }
    });
</script>

<div id="demo"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Such as my website address is: https://www.mywebsite.com/roof_material

I get a string in a variable (newPathname) which contains the text after the / sign, in this example: roof_material

**The problem is:**

I would like to find the value of this variable in a text and if you can find it then you can post it on the website. It's works if I put a text in a variable like in the script:

```
var str = "asd fgh roof_material";
```

But I would like to find the value of this variable (newPathname) in a separate html file, if it is possible like this:
The *newPathname* value such as: roof_material

In the separated .html file content:

```
<div id="protection_material">Line-X material</div>
<div id="roof_material">Roof materials</div>
<div id="pool_material">Swimming pools</div>
```

In this example I would like to find the roof_material ID in the .html file and get the content of the div: "Roof materials" and I would like to show this text on the page:

```
<div id="demo">Roof materials</div>
```

If it has positive match then show the content of the div in other cases, it will print a basic text like in the example: "Basic Text"

Could anyone help to make it happen?

Comment: You can, technically, get the content of your other `.html` file using `.load()` and then search the entire loaded HTML for your string.

Comment: @Terry
Thanks for your reply, could you help me a bit, I wrote an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

@Terry thanks for your answer!
I think I found a simpler solution, but it's not perfect:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var pathArray = window.location.href.split('=')[1];
        var secondLevelLocation = pathArray[0];
        var newPathname = "";
    for (i = 0; i < pathArray.length; i++) {
      newPathname += "";
      newPathname += pathArray[i];
    }           
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  newPathname;     
    });
</script>
<div id="demo">Országosan</div>
```

If I type it in the browser such as: https://www.mywebsite.com/index then the text that will appear in #demo div is: "Országosan"
It's good, but if I type such as: [https://www.mywebsite.com/index?id=Cserkeszőlő](https://www.mywebsite.com/index?id=Cserkesz%C5%91l%C5%91)
then the result is good but character encoding does not work properly.
The result in the #demo div: **Cserkesz%C5%91l%C5%91** , but I would like to show the correct encoded text like this: **Cserkeszőlő**

Can you give me a solution on this?